# Positive integers $n$ that cannot be written as a sum of $r$ consecutive positive integers, with $r > 1$, are of the form n = $2^l$ for some $l ≥ 0$.

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that the positive integers $n$ that cannot be written as a sum of $r$ consecutive positive integers, with $r > 1$, are of the form n = $2^l$ for some $l ≥ 0$.

I wrote just  k+(k+1)+.....(k+r-1) as $2^l$ and then by applying AP formula, it gets me to something like $r/2 ( 2k + (r-1))$ = $2^l$ which leads to nowhere.. .I did to get a contradiction.
I have shown my approach and this is not a homework problem.I need some help to move from here or a new way to solve  the problem in a less cumbersome manner.
Thank you.

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Positive_Integer_is_Sum_of_Consecutive_Positive_Integers_iff_not_Power_of_2

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3126495/prove-that-any-number-that-is-not-a-power-of-2-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-two?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

Write an expression for the sum from $k$ to $k+r-1$ using the formula for the sum of the numbers from $1$ to $n$.  Your sum is the difference of two of these.  Factor that expression and show that one of the factors is odd.  $2^l$ does not have any odd factors, but all other numbers do.

Comment: See... On summation what I get is( r/2 )* (2k + r -1)

Comment: You should be able to get a different form starting from the difference of the two triangular numbers, as I indicated.

Comment: Okay.... I will see