# Prove that the positive integers $n$ and that cannot be written as a sum of $r$ consecutive positive integers are of the form $n=2^l$ for some $l>=0$.

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

Prove that the positive integers $n$ and that cannot be written as a sum of $r$ consecutive positive integers are of the form $n=2^l$ for some $l>=0$.

Similar questions have been asked before but I want to know whether it can be proved by mathematical induction.

For $l=0, n=2^0=1$ which cannot be written as a sum of positive consecutive integers.

For $l=1, n=2$ which cannot be written as a sum of positive consecutive integers.

Let the expression be true for $l=m$,

Proof for $l=m+1$:

$n=2^{m+1}=2^m.2$

$2^m$ cannot be written as a sum of positive consecutive integers as assumed. 
Neither can $2$ be written in that way.

Hence, $2^m.2$ cannot be written as the sum of consecutive integers.

Is this correct? If no, can it be proved by mathematical induction in other any way?

Comment: you are doing the wrong direction. The intent of the problem would have been: show that, if $n$ is not a power of 2 ( including $1=2^0$), then it can be written as the sum of $r$ consecutive positive integers, for some $r \geq 2,$ For example, any odd number (at least 3) works with $r=2,$ as $3 = 1+2,$ $5 = 2+3.$  What numbers can be written with $r=3?$

Comment: @WillJagy, $18=5+6+7, 6=1+2+3$. But don't we have to prove that $2^l$ cannot be written as a sum of positive consecutive integers?

Comment: take a look at this one, fairly elaborate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3123210/which-positive-integers-can-not-be-written-as-a-sum-of-consecutive-positive-inte

Comment: Also, I suppose they do want an if-and-only-if proof.

Comment: Take a look at the solution here; https://youtu.be/yxmeK5kr9Sc